# How to see who viewed my shared excel sheet

Tags: excel, document

I want to have a shared excel document, I want to know how many users have viewed it, basically its viewing history. I have checked for google sheets but that feature is only available for people with company domains not for individual. If anything apart from google sheet that can track the viewing history will also do. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Workbook.Open event, make a call to this Sub. The user name, machine name and what time the user opened the file will be part of the filename. You can save more information when the code opens the file (see the code comment when printing to file):

```
Sub fnSaveAccessLog()
    Dim strLogFile As String
    Dim lngFF As Long
    Dim strMachine As String
    Dim strUser As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    strLogFile = "UserAccess"
    strMachine = Environ("computername")
    strUser = Environ("username")
    strDate = Year(Now) & Format(Month(Now), "00") & Format(Day(Now()), "00") & "_" & _
        Format(Hour(Now()), "00") & Format(Minute(Now()), "00") & Format(Second(Now()), "00")
    strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs\" & strLogFile & "_" _
        & strDate & "_" & strUser & "_" & strMachine & ".txt"

    lngFF = VBA.FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Output As #lngFF
    Print #lngFF, "put more info here if desired"
    Close #lngFF
    
End Sub
```

After reading @indnwkybrd's comments I modified the code, to implement the two commented suggestions (thanks!) and simplified the construction of the filename variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnAppendAccessLog()
    Dim lngFF As Long
    Dim strMachine As String
    Dim strUser As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    strMachine = Environ("computername")
    strUser = Environ("username")
    strDate = Format$(Now, "yyyyMMDD_hhmmss")
    strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs\" & "UsersAccessLog - " & Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".txt"

    lngFF = VBA.FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Append As #lngFF
    Print #lngFF, Join$(Array(strUser, strMachine, strDate), vbTab)
    Close #lngFF
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also just do `strDate = Format$(Now, "yyyyMMDD_hhmmss")` to simplify a bit.

Comment: Another variant: if you just wanted to have a single log file, with info on who accessed it when as a list, you could do `Open strLogFile For Append As #lngFF` and `Print #lngFF, Join$(Array(strUser, strMachine, strDate), vbTab)`

Comment: @indnwkybrd Thanks for the suggestions. implemented. The original code was used in massive monitoring where individual access was the best approach, and I copied it almost 'as is'.

Comment: Can this code be used in shared excel? for Google sheets or Office Excel? @ALeXceL

Comment: @ChetanAciduniform16Kondawle This is s VBA macro to run on the Excel Workbook_Open event. To run a Google Sheets macro you'll have to do it on GAS - Google Apps Script :-|